# Codeigniter validation is not working on my live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have placed below code for codeigniter validation,

```
 $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');




$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|max_length[100]|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|max_length[64]');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s can not be blank.');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_email', 'Please enter valid email address');

        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {

        } else {
}
```

This code is working fine with my local system ,my local system it is windows,

On server ,it is linux, and sentOS

in both my local system and server both have php version is 5.6

but my validation is not working there , can you give me any suggestion that what thing I need to check,

on live server it goes into if condition instead of else part.

,I found that I am not able to get my form data in my controller ,my form data is comming with post request not able to get $_POST result.

can you give me any idea what I can do ???

Comment: show your full method code

Comment: I found that there is error not because of form validation , but in my server I am not able to get $_POST data

Comment: use `print_r($this->input->post());` in your method

Comment: not able to get any result in this. it shows me blank array.  for same array with same code I am able to work with my local system but on server it is giving me blank array

Comment: have u change or set base url for the live server

Comment: I have checked it in config/config.php file , it is set properly. any other luck to check ??

Comment: in this case pls show ur form and method code

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are go to live,please make sure this points for complete running form

1.please check php.ini file and increase values of **post_max_size** and **upload_max_filesize** and make sure value of upload_max_filesize is less than post_max_size.
2.set `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');` then after you do not need to load it in any controller.
3.in `routes.php` class names have only first character is capital.